# How to select one random id from the child table?

Tags: sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group, mariadb-10.4

I am using 10.4.13-MariaDB. I have a parent table and a child table.

Parent table (tasks)

```
id parent_id
4    # <- Main (parent theme) Level 2
5    4 <- child `discovered check` (level 2)
6    4 <- child  `windmill`  (level 2)
7    # <- Main (parent theme) Level 3
8    7 <- child `discovered check - level 3` (level 3)
9    7 <- child  `windmill - level 3`  (level 3)
10    # <- Main (parent theme) Level 1
11    10 <- child `discovered check - winning a piece` (level 1)
12    10 <- child  `discovered check - mate in one`  (level 1)
```

In interface it looks like

[image]

And I have a child table (puzzles) - puzzles table - puzzles can belong only to child themes

```
 id      task_id
 52         5 <- belongs to `discovered check` (level 2)
 61         6 <- belongs to `windmill` (level 2)
 25         6 <- belongs to `windmill` (level 2)
 70         11 <- belongs to `discovered check - winning a piece` (level 1)
 53         12 <- belongs to `discovered check - mate in 1` (level 1)
 62         9 <- belongs to `windmill - level 3` (level 3)
 27         9 <- belongs to `windmill - level 3` - (level 3)
 72         8 <- belongs to `discovered check - level 3` - (level 3)
```

I want to get ONE random PUZZLE from EACH LEVEL. How to write a proper query?

**Expected result:**

```
task_id  id
  5      52 <- random puzzle from level 2
  11     70 <- random puzzle from level 1
  8      72 <- random puzzle from level 3
```

My fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=7bed2a19a0f98abccbe06ba9e0ae358b

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? And why does the `puzzles` table have both an `id` and a `puzzle_id`? I'd expect a puzzle's ID to *be* the puzzle ID. What's the difference? Must you select both or would it suffice to select only one of the two?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are right, updated

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am using 10.4.13-MariaDB

Comment: Okay, so you have tagged your request with the wrong DBMS. They are extremely close, but not equal. I've corrected the tags.

Comment: Post also your expected result, one of all the possible expected results.

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you call "level" here. In hierarchies the level is usually the depth in the tree. You, however, use it like a group number for a main ID. So, the difference to your original request is only that you don't want to restrict the randomly picked puzzles to depth 2. I.e. you want a recursive query to collect all puzzles belonging to a main task ID first and only then pick the puzzles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
with cte as (
  select p.*, row_number() over (partition by t.parent_id order by rand()) rn
  from puzzles p inner join tasks t  
  on t.id = p.task_id
)
select task_id, id
from cte 
where rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d2c3d00d69491db97969d15bcbad4ac4).

Partition of `row_number()` should be by the column `parent_id` of `tasks`, so the result has 1 row for each theme.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT tasks.id task_id, 
                     puzzles.puzzle_id, 
                     row_number() over (partition by tasks.id order by rand()) rn
              FROM tasks
              JOIN puzzles ON tasks.id = puzzles.task_id )
SELECT task_id, puzzle_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Needs version 8.0+ or MariaDB 10.2+

```sql
select tasks.id task_id, rand_puzzle.puzzle_id
from tasks,
     lateral ( select puzzle_id
               from puzzles
               where tasks.id = puzzles.task_id 
               order by rand() limit 1 ) rand_puzzle;
```

Needs version 8.0.14+.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f9b42d3bf7d6b6fcb6ed43360c982b4)

If you need the data for some subtree only extract this subtree from `tasks` table in recursive CTE previously.

Comment: thank you, but I need only one puzzle from eache level, added fiddle to question

Answer (score 0):

You want one puzzle per main task. So hierarchally find all tasks belonging to a main task first (with a recursive query), then join the puzzles and pick one per main task.

(The main task is what you call "level" in your request.)

```
with recursive cte (main_task_id, task_id) as
(
  select parent_id, task_id
  from tasks
  where parent_id in (select id from tasks where parent_id is null)
  union all
  select cte.main_task_id, t.task_id
  from cte
  join tasks t on t.parent_id = cte.task_id
)
, randomly_numbered as
(
  select
    cte.main_task_id,
    p.task_id,
    p.id as puzzle_id,
    row_number() over (partition by main_task_id order by rand()) as rn
  from cte
  join puzzle p on p.task_id = cte.task_id
)
select
  -- main_task_id,
  task_id,
  puzzle_id
from randomly_numbered
where rn = 1
order by main_task_id;
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but I need a random puzzle for ONE OF THEME united by one parent theme, only one puzzle from `Level 2`, looks like my question is not precise, I will edit it

Comment: edited the question and added fiddle with your answer and Akina's

Comment: Okay, you don't want to restrict the puzzles to depth 2 in your hierarchy. So, you need a recursive query first to get all puzzles belonging to a main task. I've updated my answer.